# Duplicate Struct in C++

Tags: c++, object, struct, copy

How can I go about copying one `struct` to another. Currently, the following code compiles but keeps on crashing on runtime. Is there a better way to do this?

```
struct Trip
{
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int endX;
    int endY;
    int suppress
};

struct Feedback
{
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int endX;
    int endY;
    int suppress;
};

vector<Trip> tripList;
vector<Trip> TTMx[288]; 
TTMX[0] = &tripList;
vector<Feedback> Tripfeed[288];

    for(time = 0; time < 288; time++){
            for (int trp=0; trp < tripList.size(); trp++) {

                Tripfeed[time][trp].startX = tripList[trp].startX;
                Tripfeed[time][trp].startY = tripList[trp].startY;
                Tripfeed[time][trp].endX = tripList[trp].endX;
                Tripfeed[time][trp].endY = tripList[trp].endY;
                Tripfeed[time][trp].suppress = tripList[trp].suppress;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You have an array of 288 empty vectors. To add elements to one vector, use `push_back`.

Comment: How to use push_back to add data to object startX?

Comment: What is `tripList`? you should be able to use this one statement inside your for loops `Tripfeed[time].push_back(tripList[trp])`

Comment: If I eliminate this copying routine, my main code runs fine. Hence, I have to assume that the issue has to be related to the above code.

Comment: Post a [mcve], please.

Comment: @Far  You showed an invalid definition of  Trip because the definition does not contain data member suppress

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It has been added.

Comment: @Far What is the sense to declare the same structure with different names?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Good question, there are some members in Trip that I do not care to include in Tripfeed. I do not need another 10 members in Feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tripfeed is declared as an array of 288 empty vectors.  They are empty, because this is the behavior of the default constructor of the vector class.  It crashes due to an access violation when you try to access elements of those vectors, since the vectors are empty.  For each vector you must resize it to the desired size prior to accessing its elements.  Here is the correct code:

```
struct Feedback
{
    int startX;
    int startY;
    int endX;
    int endY;
    int suppress;
};

vector<Feedback> Tripfeed[288];

for(time = 0; time < 288; time++)
{

    Tripfeed[time].resize (tripList.size());

    for (int trp=0; trp < tripList.size(); trp++) 
    {
        Tripfeed[time][trp].startX = tripList[trp].startX;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].startY = tripList[trp].startY;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].endX = tripList[trp].endX;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].endY = tripList[trp].endY;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].suppress = tripList[trp].suppress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I usually prefer push_back just so I do not have to resize, however I should have realized this.

Comment: If you know the size of the vector in advance you get much better performance, because there is only one memory allocation.  If you had 1000 items that you pushed back individually the vector keeps growing as needed.  Each time it grows it has to allocate a larger chunk of memory, copy the old memory to the new memory, and then delete the old memory.

Answer (score 0):

your declaration of Tripfeed should be

```
    vector<vector<Feedback>> Tripfeed(288, vector<Feedback>(tripList.size(), Feedback()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a decent compiler with range based for loop available:

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

for (std::vector<Feedback>& f : Tripfeed)
{
  f.resize(tripList.size()); // all vectors in Tripfeed are initially empty
  std::copy(tripList.begin(), tripList.end(), f.begin());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use resize() to allocate enough memory to the vector. your code should be something like below. However, I recommend to use 2D vectors to declare Tripfeed (std::vector < std::vector < Feedback > > Tripfeed).

```
for(int time = 0; time < 288; time++){
    Tripfeed[time].resize(tripList.size());
    for (int trp=0; trp < tripList.size(); trp++) {
        Tripfeed[time][trp].startX = tripList[trp].startX;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].startY = tripList[trp].startY;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].endX = tripList[trp].endX;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].endY = tripList[trp].endY;
        Tripfeed[time][trp].suppress = tripList[trp].suppress;
    }
  }
```